# Combo Box parameter has no default value in delphi

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe3

The program I'm working on uses an if statement to add a line to the SQL for the contents of another combo box

```
procedure TFmNewGarage.ComboBoxCountryEnter(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ADOQueryCountry.SQL.Clear;
  ADOQueryCountry.SQL.Add('SELECT DISTINCT Country');
  ADOQueryCountry.SQL.Add(' FROM TblBaseCar');
  ADOQueryCountry.Open;
  while not ADOQueryCountry.Eof do
  begin
  ComboBoxCountry.Items.Add(ADOQueryCountry['Country']);
  ADOQueryCountry.Next;
  end;
end;

procedure TFmNewGarage.ComboBoxCountryChange(Sender: TObject);
begin
  SelA:=True;
  ComboBoxManufacturer.Show;
  ComboBoxCountry.Hide;
end;

procedure TFmNewGarage.ComboBoxManufacturerEnter(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ADOQueryManufacturer.SQL.Clear;
  ADOQueryManufacturer.SQL.Add('SELECT DISTINCT Manufacturer');
  ADOQueryManufacturer.SQL.Add(' FROM TblBaseCar');
  if SelA=true then
  ADOQueryManufacturer.SQL.Add(' WHERE Country=(ComboBoxCountry.seltext)');
  ADOQueryManufacturer.Open;
  while not ADOQueryManufacturer.Eof do
  begin
  ComboBoxManufacturer.Items.Add(ADOQueryManufacturer['Manufacturer']);
  ADOQueryManufacturer.Next;
  end;
end;
```

At runtime this results in the error ComboBoxCountry.seltext has no default value, can anyone help me to rectify this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SelText` is not the property you should be using. You need the combobox `Items` value for the chosen `ItemIndex`:

```
var
 Country: string;
begin
  ...
  if ComboBoxCountry.ItemIndex <> -1 then
  begin
    Country := ComboBoxCountryItems[ComboBoxCountry.ItemIndex];
    ADOQueryManufacturer.SQL.Add('WHERE Country = ' + QuotedStr(Country));
  end;
end;
```

Comment: it seems to get further before crashing now, but still raises an exception saying, for example, Parameter Canada has no default value

Comment: I've edited my code slightly; see if that change helps. You're not showing any use of `Parameter`s in your code at all (you're not using a parameterized query in either SQL statement, based on the code you provided). I can't explain that problem, because you haven't given any information that would relate to it. I'm suspecting it's because there were no quotes around the variable being added to the SQL.

Comment: There is no use of parameter in my code whatsoever, it is going to add all this to a database later though, and I'm not sure wether this will affect it at all

Comment: I did, as I said it's raising a slightly different exception now to the one it was raising

Comment: Matthew, that was **before** I edited my code. Did you try the **changed code** I posted? If that doesn't fix it, you're going to need to edit your question and provide more details. EDIT: I see it must have. :-)

Comment: Sorry, just noticed the modification to the answer, it's working now

Comment: Thank you very much for the help and sorry for any inconvenience I caused